# vectors and threading in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I would like to request for comments/ideas on how to resolve a vector and threading issue that is becoming a bit convoluted. I have researched the issue and have not found a working solution.

The intention is to have 5 person objects (stored in a vector) and then call each of their method to read a book concurrently (hence the threads). The read function contains a never ending loop.

I have the following code(simplified) set up:

```
class Book{
    private:
         // some data                                                                                   
    public:
        // some functions                                                                              
};

class Person{
    private:
        // some data vars                                                                              
        int id;
        Book abook;
    public:
        // some functions                                                                              
        Person(int index=0);  // constructor                                                           
        void readBook();
};

int main(void){

    vector<Person>PersonsVector;
    vector<thread> threads;
    int num_of_persons = 5;

    for(int i=0; i<num_of_persons; i++){
        PersonsVector.push(Person(i));  //create different people       
        threads.push_back(thread(PersonsVector[i].readBook)); //read book in thread        
    }

   // wait for threads to finnish or kill threads                                                 
    for(auto& thread: threads) 
        threads.join();
}
```

My issue is really in how to call the readBook() function and push this to a thread

```
 threads.push_back(thread(PersonsVector[i].readBook)); //read book in thread
```

Various variations for example these below lead to errors...

```
 threads.push_back(thread(&PersonsVector[i].Person::readBook, this));             
 threads.push_back(thread(&Person::PersonsVector[i].Person::readBook, this));
```

Any ideas how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: why not use threads.emplace instead?

Comment: @user `emplace()` is always better or at least the same, and here it's going to be the same because we are moving in a temporary. Anyway, that is not the problem here.

Comment: Aside: pushing to the back of a vector can invalidate references into the vector. Since I expect a fixed version of your code will use references to the persons, use `reserve` to ensure that reallocation doesn't happen, or make it a `deque` or `list` instead.

Comment: @Hurkly noted. Not familiar with emplace at the moment, will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer-to-method must be called using a combination of a pointer specifying the class and method + an instance of said class on which to invoke said method.

This... thing:

`&Person::PersonsVector[i].Person::readBook`

actually says...

- Get me the class `Person`,
- then a `vector` within an unspecified instance of `Person`, which does not contain any such `vector`...
- then an index `i` within that invalid `vector`,
- then somehow get the constructor of that instance,
- then somehow get a method `readBook()` from within that constructor.

See the problem? That's invalid syntax in so many varied ways.

The correct syntaxes are as follows:

- For the pointer-to-method: `&Person::readBook`
- For the instance: `PersonsVector[i]`

...and you need to give these to `std::thread` via some mechanism that will bundle the pointer-to-method and instance and make them callable for you - such as a lambda, `std::bind`, etc. - something like this:

```
std::thread theThread{
    [] // not sure which capture is needed... :/
    {
        (someInstance.*pointerToMethod)(the, args);
        // i.e.
        (PersonsVector[i].*readBook)();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot people, this solution solved the problem. I agree with your observation that that particular statement was not making sense, -was some last attempt at trying to get it to work before calling for backup :)

Comment: @Dennis I advise you don't fire up those threads at the same time you're pushing items into the container. if the vector resizes during the fill loop, all those instance pointers passed into prior thread launches will become invalid; accessing them in the threads therefore invokes *undefined behavior*. If you still want to do both within the same loop (fill the container *and* launch the threads), you need to pick another container (such as a `std::list`). Or, reserve space for all items via `std::vector::reserve()`

Comment: @WhozCraig, I actually had that memory reserved so perhaps nothing to worry about at the moment, but the point you raised is still valid from a robustness perspective.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for adding that. It's essential! `vector` is highly prone to invalidating iterators (in the sense that also covers references and pointers), which doesn't make it a bad choice of container but means that if such iterators are important, we absolutely must `reserve()` carefully well in advance. Often `vector` is just the ticket if used sensibly. But you're right that if a program requires acrobatics mandating highly stable iterators, it might need to instead use a `list` or something else.

Comment: @Dennis the code presented in the question does *not* have a reserve, which is why I brought it up. So long as you understand.

Comment: I should mention that this solution compiles for g++6.X but not for g++4.X (that ships with OS X). the 4.x version complains :error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::thread'

Comment: @Dennis That version must be so old that either (A) it did not have that specific facet of the library implemented, or perhaps more likely (B) it does not default to C++14 (with GNU extensions) as `g++` 6 does, meaning you might have to tell it to compile with that version if (I don't know) `thread` got more features in that revision. There's a point: tell us which switches you are using to compile! And `v.X` is not a useful report of version number... we can infer `6.1`, but `4.`what?

Comment: @underscore_d the versions i meant are 4.2.1 vs 6.1.0 there are no special flags passed to the compiler: g++-6 -Wall person.cpp book.cpp app.cpp -o app.o

Comment: @Dennis Then I'm right: You need to tell it to compile as a barely modern C++ version. 4.2.1 compiles as the incredibly vintage C++ _98_ by default, which doesn't even _have_ `<thread>`, so it's a wonder it got as far as it did before errorring out. Threads were added to the Standard Library in C++11. You can search and find out how to configure your compiler properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda:
`threads.push_back(thread([&PersonsVector[i]])(Person& p){ p.readBook(); });`

Comment: thanks but this caused some issues too. Solution proposed above by @underscore_d worked fine.